# Чем String отличается от string в c++?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Чем это:

```
string str;
```

Отличается от этого:

```
String str;
```

И что лучше использовать?

Comment: Чем угодно. В C++ нет никакого `String`, поэтому уточните что это такое?

Comment: В `iostream` нет типа `String` (с большой буквы). Откуда он? Кстати, типа `string` там тоже нет, но есть `std::string`. Укажите **пространства имён**! У вас там где-то в начале файла `using namespace ...`. PS: блин, ощущение, что я не с программистом общаюсь...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да у меня времени нет, вот и пишу всякую чепуху по быстрому...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` - это `std::string` - изменяемая строка из однобайтовых символов из стандартной библиотеки си++. Работа с такими строками осуществляется по обычным правилам си++. Однко, стоит задуматься об использовании юникодных строк, например, `wstring`.

`String` - это `System.String` из .net - юникодная строка из .net. Хотя приведённый код корректен, он практически бесполезен. В большинстве случаев понадобится что-то в духе `String ^str`, что означает не сам объект, а указатель на объект, находящийся в памяти, управляемой сборщиком мусора .net. Такие строки следует использовать для взаимодействия с .net. К тому же, запрещено смешивать станартные и дотнетные сущности в одном объекте.

Comment: Ответ с вероятностью 99,(9)% правильный. Но всё же, так как автор вопроса не указал, из каких неймспейсов эти типы, то есть вероятность, что они из других библиотек. (@VerNick примите меры).

Comment: Вы уверены, что невозможно положить оба типа строк в один объект? Не знал.

Comment: @VladD, вообще-то не уверен. Там скорее что внутрь ref class нельзя помещать объекты из std (а может, указатели?). Ну и это было в 2005, может они уже переделали.